# Trying to fix phpunit tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

For my Laravel app I'm trying to create a Unit test that atttempts to get a count of all of the states I have in my State filter. The test does not need a user or roles or permissions to be able to run however with my test it extends this TestCase file. When I run my test its reporting that the roles table does not exist.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I should do?

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Permission;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse;

abstract class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
use CreatesApplication;

protected $authorizedUser;
protected $unauthorizedUser;

/**
 * The base URL to use while testing the application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $baseUrl = 'http://ringside.app';

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    TestResponse::macro('data', function ($key) {
        return $this->original->getData()[$key];
    });

    Collection::macro('assertContains', function ($value) {
        Assert::assertTrue($this->contains($value), 'Failed asserting that the collection contains the specified value.');
    });

    Collection::macro('assertNotContains', function ($value) {
        Assert::assertFalse($this->contains($value), 'Failed asserting that the collection does not contain the specified value.');
    });

    Collection::macro('assertEquals', function ($items) {
        Assert::assertEquals(count($this), count($items));
        $this->zip($items)->each(function ($pair) {
            list($a, $b) = $pair;
            Assert::assertTrue($a->is($b));
        });
    });

    $this->setupUnauthorizedUser();
    $this->setupWrestlerStatuses();
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized user of the included permissions.
 *
 * @param array $slugs
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupAuthorizedUser($slugs)
{
    $this->authorizedUser = factory(User::class)->create();
    $role = factory(Role::class)->create();

    if (is_array($slugs)) {
        foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
            $permission = factory(Permission::class)->create(['slug' => $slug]);
            $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
        }
    } else {
        $permission = factory(Permission::class)->create(['slug' => $slugs]);
        $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
    }

    $this->authorizedUser->assignRole($role);
}

protected function setupUnauthorizedUser()
{
    $this->unauthorizedUser = factory(User::class)->create();
    $role = factory(Role::class)->create();
    $this->unauthorizedUser->assignRole($role);
}
}

<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Utilities;

use Tests\TestCase;

class StateTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_can_get_all_states()
    {
         $this->assertEquals(50, count(State::all()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use a different database for testing and production? Did you do `php artisan migrate` using the testing database?

Comment: This is all with a sqlite database in memory.

Comment: I'm not really understanding then. If the error says that the roles table doesn't exist, you need to either create it or not query it.

Comment: you should use Artisan::call("migrate") at setUp() function and Artisan::call("migrate:reset") at tearDown() function